# Xamarin Android Sharing Intent under Marshmallow

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, file-sharing

In my Application I try to share an Image with the Intent (**Intent.ActionSend**).
For the guaranteed Access I use a **Fileprovider** which creates the Uri to the file.
Under Android **Nougat my code works** but with **Marshmallow not**. It shows no errors but the Image is not sent to the recieving App.
The Output from VisualStudio also shows no errors or somthing like that.

I couldn't find any answer online so far. What is the problem with Marshmallow?

```
public void SendPhoto(IEnumerable<string> photos, string text)
    {            
        var files = new List<Android.Net.Uri>();
        //creates for every photo an own ContentURI
        foreach (var path in photos)
        {
            var file = new Java.IO.File(path);                
            files.Add(FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Context, "com.testapp.fileprovider", file));
        }
        //Checks if Photolist are empty
        if (!files.Any())
            throw new Exception("Photos not found");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.SetType("image/jpeg");
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject");
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, files.First());
        //creates the sharemessage
        var shareMessage = files.Count == 1 ? "Send photo from TestApp" : "Send photos from TestApp";
        //start Intent chooser
        Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, shareMessage));

    }
```

Comment: what error you get?share stackTrace.

Comment: I get not error. Thats the problem.